# Protractor - Clear LocalStorage to Loss Connection on Spec

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angular-local-storage

I'm using `window.localStorage.removeItem("name of localStorage variable you want to remove");` to delete two different localStorage Keys in a spec, they're successfully deleted.

The next step is to enter another page of my application to display a dialog that ask you to log in again due to session lost, but doing this with protractor doesn't not work even that the localStorage keys are cleared correctly, but doing it manually (deleting them giving right click and Delete), it works and dialog pops up.

What could be the problem?

Comment: How do you clear session and local storage manually? Is that some plugin? Or just devtools?

Comment: Just devtools, deleting them from there (Application->LocalStorage->Delete the two keys), manually works and after changing from another state the dialog asking me to log in again appears, but when the test is running it doesn't work, the keys just appear again without asking log in again.

Answer (score 0):

Consider wiping cookies, local and session storage fully, instead of wiping only 2 keys.

```
browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear(); window.localStorage.clear();')
```

Comment: Didn't work :S I can't find the reason why if I do it manually it works and if protractor does it, it doesn't work :S

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your site stores cookies for different domain, or httponly cookies.

Webdriver can delete only cookies for the same domain where are you currently located. So if your API gives you some authtoken - it won't be deleted, since it is stored for different domain. The same for HTTPonly cookies.

```
HttpOnly cookie
An HttpOnly cookie cannot be accessed by client-side APIs, such as JavaScript. This restriction eliminates the threat of cookie theft via cross-site scripting (XSS). However, the cookie remains vulnerable to cross-site tracing (XST) and cross-site request forgery (XSRF) attacks. A cookie is given this characteristic by adding the HttpOnly flag to the cookie.
```

I would suggest you to navigate to API url, and call `browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();` method there or call manually logout on your site